# ValueError: bad input shape (100, 752)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to run naive bayes model using scikit however it's giving me this error and I can't seem to figure out what the problem is?

```
# Gaussian Naive Bayes
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
# load the iris datasets
#dataset = datasets.load_iris()
# fit a Naive Bayes model to the data
model = GaussianNB()
model.fit(training_set, testing_set)
print(model)
# make predictions
expected = testing_set
predicted = model.predict(training_set)
# summarize the fit of the model
print(metrics.classification_report(expected, predicted))
print(metrics.confusion_matrix(expected, predicted))
```

I think the problem is in training_set and testing_set but I'm not sure and don't know how to solve it, I have split the data in training and testing

```
training_set=newdf.sample(frac=0.7,random_state=200)
testing_set=newdf.drop(train.index)
```

The code works fine if I I use iris data

```
# Gaussian Naive Bayes
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
# load the iris datasets
dataset = datasets.load_iris()
# fit a Naive Bayes model to the data
model = GaussianNB()
model.fit(dataset.data, dataset.target)
print(model)
# make predictions
expected = dataset.target
predicted = model.predict(dataset.data)
# summarize the fit of the model
print(metrics.classification_report(expected, predicted))
print(metrics.confusion_matrix(expected, predicted))
```

How can I remove this error?

```
Traceback

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-072d1f083190> in <module>()
      7 # fit a Naive Bayes model to the data
      8 model = GaussianNB()
----> 9 model.fit(training_set, testing_set)
     10 print(model)
     11 # make predictions

D:\python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    171             Returns self.
    172         """
--> 173         X, y = check_X_y(X, y)
    174         return self._partial_fit(X, y, np.unique(y), _refit=True,
    175                                  sample_weight=sample_weight)

D:\python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.pyc in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    513                         dtype=None)
    514     else:
--> 515         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
    516         _assert_all_finite(y)
    517     if y_numeric and y.dtype.kind == 'O':

D:\python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.pyc in column_or_1d(y, warn)
    549         return np.ravel(y)
    550 
--> 551     raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
    552 
    553 

ValueError: bad input shape (100, 752)
```

Comment: looks to me like `model.fit` is expecting `testing_set` to be a 1D vector, whereas you're passing a 2D array with shape (100, 752) as input.

Comment: Should I convert 2D to 1D? the dataset is quite big with some 10000 rows and 771 columns

Comment: i have no idea how your data are arranged or what they mean.  you're going to have to think about your data with regard to what `model.fit` is expecting.  if you understand conceptually the analysis you're trying to perform, you should be able to figure this out.

Comment: you're not sharing here what `newdf` or `train` is, as far as i can tell.

Comment: nedwdf is may dataframe and for train i don't know i took this code online and this is my first python assignment if that explains something

Comment: also I don;t think it's the problem with 2D or 1D my data is in the same format as iris and iris works fine soo...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110682/discussion-between-dbliss-and-hyeri).